# Adding Threejs addon to Angular 4

Tags: angular, three.js, ionic3

I want to add a new loader into the threejs library, the only problem is that I'm using Ionic 3/Angular 4. I've got threejs running using this example https://github.com/u4bi/simple-angular4-threejs no issues, but I want to add another 3rd party library - THREE.JDLoader() (http://www.cgdev.net/json/download.php).

I've tried adding

```
  <script src="assets/JDLoader.min.js"></script>
```

into index.html but I get

```
 ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
    at http://localhost:8100/assets/JDLoader.min.js:1:1
```

I also get an error in the IDE unresolved type JDloader -

```
  var loader = new THREE.JDLoader();
```

to get around this I used

```
var loader2 = new (THREE as any).JDLoader();
```

Comment: import it as an ES module ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean

Comment: import { yourLoader} from 'JDloader or what ever the package name is from npm'; and use it

Comment: it's not in npm